# string.format() with {} inside string as string

Tags: python, string

Ponder that you have a string which looks like the following `'This string is {{}}'` and you would like to transform it into the following `'This string is {wonderful}'`

if you do `'This string is {{}}'.format('wonderful')` it won't work. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need one more pair of `{}`

```
'This string is {{{}}}'.format('wonderful')
```

Comment: Superb, it looks ridiculous, but it works :)

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah, I wish it was `\{`.

Answer (score 3):

you need triple brackets: two for the literal `{`  and `}`and the pair in the middle for the format function.

```
print('This string is {{{}}}'.format('wonderful'))
```

Comment: I think they were revoked because you added the explanation.

Comment: @vaultah that's kind of the MO for questions a simple as that. everyone posts code as fast as possible and then adds an explanation later. ninja-editing... i did so as well... (and had to answer a captcha).

Comment: ["You are welcome to post a first version of your answer as fast as you can, provided it is already a correct and useful answer meeting our minimal standards."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303449/2301450)

Comment: @vaultah thanks. interesting meta-post!

Answer (score 1):

Two brackets to get `{}` in line (escaping), and third as placeholder:

```
'This string is {{{}}}'.format('wonderful')
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this: `print "{{f}}".format(f='wonderful')`.

You can do this as well: `"Hello, {name}!".format(name='John')`. This will substitute all `{name}`s with `John`.